# Magento onestepcheckout change billing address fields order

Tags: php, magento

I want to change the order of the billing address fields on onestepcheckout page. I found from  the admin onestepcheckout settongs "field position management" But a message displays here "Configure positions of fields in Section Billing and Shipping Address. You can display fields into 2 columns (eg: First name + Last name) or 1 full column (eg: Address + Null)".

I change the order her but its not reflecting. Also I am unable to find the billing and shipping address section. Pleas help me to find this secion.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a paid 3rd party extension so the best option would be to contact extension provider support to get the answer.

And in all cases when you are using paid extensions try to solve your issues with support first then ask as:

- other developers most probably don't have access to source to help you out
- your questions in open internet are indexed and may just cost a sale for the extension provider
- your questions in open internet might not get the extension provider attention

Answer (score 1):

You can do that from Admin > System > Configuration > Onestepcheckout

http://www.YOURWEBSITE.com/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/onestepcheckout/